# Bootstrap image position in jumbotron

Tags: css, image, position

Seems like I can't get that image to be aligned with the Text.
I am trying to get that logo aligned with those two sentences.

Also, There was no style setting. Just the default Bootstrap.css file.

```html
<div class="box-padding-md grey-bg">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="../img/bg.png" style="float:left;width:150px;height:150px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px;">
      <h3 class="display-5">"Espher Information Assocation"</h3>
      <p class="lead">제16세대 프로젝트</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Photo of the result]

Comment: What do you mean by "aligned"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with bootstrap media object, no need to use any css for that.
Check that link you can have a better idea
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Bootstrap Media</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-padding-md grey-bg">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">  
        <div class="media p-3">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/v9f1nS2.jpg" alt="John Doe" class="mr-3 mt-3 rounded-circle" style="width:60px;">
           <div class="media-body">
            <h3 class="display-5">"Espher Information Assocation"</h3>
            <p class="lead">제16세대 프로젝트</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a miracle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<style>
.align{
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
   margin-left:20px;
   margin-right:20px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}
<style>

In HTML use this

<a class="align"><img src="../img/bg.png" alt=""></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but, result came out the same.

Comment: you can use bootstrap class < a class="navbar-brand visible-xs">

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid system: https://jsfiddle.net/wwWaldi/3xy4woq7/13/

```
<div class="box-padding-md grey-bg">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-4 text-right">
           <img src="../img/bg.png" id="myImg" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class="display-5">"Espher Information Assocation"</h3>
          <p class="lead">제16세대 프로젝트</p>    
        </div> 
        <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked but, seems to have a little trouble with the mobile. I'll get it figured out